# Ionic App.component.html Session not showing

Tags: android, html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to show session in html called `{{nama_cust}}` at app.component.html, but it didn't show anything / blank, is something wrong with the code? Or app.component can't process session?
Here's my code.

**app.component.html**

```
 <ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane>
    <ion-menu type="overlay" id="menu-avatar">
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title>{{nama_cust}}</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <div #header>
                <ion-row style="align-items:center;">
                  <ion-col col-6>
                    <img class="user-avatar" (click)="asd()" src="assets/ava/dum.jpg"/>
                  </ion-col>
                  <ion-col col-3>
                    <h4 id="tes"> {{nama_cust}} </h4>
                  </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
              </div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, NgModule, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, ToastController, IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Storage, IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { PostProvider } from 'src/providers/post-provider';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public appPages = [
    {
      title: 'Home',
      url: '/home',
      icon: 'home'
    },
    {
      title: 'List',
      url: '/list',
      icon: 'list'
    }
  ];

  anggota: any;
  nama_cust: string;

  constructor(
   private router: Router,
   private postPvdr: PostProvider,
   private storage: Storage,
   public toastCtrl: ToastController,
   private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.storage.get('session_storage').then((res) => {
      this.anggota = res;
      this.nama_cust = sessionStorage.getItem(this.nama_cust);
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
}
```

`console.log(res)` is showing the content of the session, but when I call the session in the html as `{{nama_cust}}` it shows nothing. [Here's how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leRDT.jpg), there should be a text above the cat picture and next to it, but it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `getItem()` on `sessionStorage` with an `undefined` key:

```
this.nama_cust = sessionStorage.getItem(this.nama_cust);
```

So there's nothing to retrieve that's why you're not seeing anything. 
`nama_cust` has been initialized, but doesn't have a value assigned.

You need to get it from the response:

```
this.storage.get('session_storage').then((res) => {
  this.anggota = res;
  this.nama_cust = res.result.nama_cust;
  console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: thank you, its working now but it only appear after i refresh it. any suggestion?

Comment: Use the async pipe when interpolating it. {{nama_cust | async }}